# How to fix RVM installation error on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4

Tags: ruby, rvm

When running

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

via the command line, I get some errors, which after researching, I cannot resolve:

```
Error running 'env GEM_HOME=/Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global GEM_PATH= /Users/****/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -d /Users/****/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.8/setup.rb --no-document',
please read /Users/****/.rvm/log/1588872415_ruby-2.3.1/rubygems.install.log
```

I installed and reinstalled OpenSSL which did not work.

Also, I tried:

```
rvm get stable
rvm autolibs enable
rvm reinstall all --force
```

which did not work either.

Comment: What does `please read /Users/****/.rvm/log/1588872415_ruby-2.3.1/rubygems.install.log` tell you? Copy the _error_ from the file, and paste that into the question. Did you follow the installation directions at https://rvm.io/? That is THE source for installation and debugging help for RVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install the Apple Developers Toolkit (XCode) from the Mac App Store (it's free) first (if it's not installed yet), then you need to install the CLI command line utilities by running:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then try your install again.

If it will not helped, try to:

1. Install rvm master with [rvm get master](https://gist.github.com/jdashton/b8e79491b0cb27ae2b41f902dd9d2a9a);
2. Reinstall rvm:

   ```
   rvm implode
   \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
   rvm pkg install openssl
   rvm install 2.3.1 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
   ```

Comment: So if it is work, mark my recommendations as "Answer" to help other users with such problem. Thanks!